# How can I get my content centered in this responsive div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 4 columns in a row that become 1 column on mobile. The way this looks on mobile is fine, but I want to center the content in divs 2 and 4 in each row. What would be the best way to do this?

Apparently my edit was deleted or the site messed up, but I had said I want to do this vertical and horizontal. However, it was my fault I forgot to link to the page. Sorry, guys. - http://www.dismantledesign.com/testsite2/clients.html

Edit: I appreciate all the answers, but I don't think anyone understands that this div has no set height. I just want that text and icons to stay centered as the screen moves. The flex didn't seem to work because it required setting a height to the div.

I also simplified my HTML

Code

```css
.clientsdetail {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
}
.clientinfo h3 {
  padding-top: 10px;;
}
.clientinfo p {
  padding: 0px 30px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 nopadding">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/clients/ivey.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 nopadding cinfo">
      <div class="clientinfo text-center">
        <h3>IVEY</h3>
        <p>Clarksville, TN</p>
        <div class="social-icons-clients">
          <a href="#"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-ig">&nbsp;</span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-fb">&nbsp;</span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-gp">&nbsp;</span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-sc">&nbsp;</span></a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/contracoda" target="_blank"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-tw">&nbsp;</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 nopadding cinfo">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="img/clients/rufus.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 nopadding">
      <div class="clientinfo text-center">
        <h3>RUFUS DAWKINS</h3>
        <p>Clarksville, TN</p>
        <div class="social-icons-clients">
          <a href="#"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-ig">&nbsp;</span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-fb">&nbsp;</span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-gp">&nbsp;</span></a>
          <a href="#"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-sc">&nbsp;</span></a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/contracoda" target="_blank"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-tw">&nbsp;</span></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: you are forgot to closed the <span> tag...

Comment: It looks like I missed the span tag in a lot of paces with these sprites. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

**(UPDATED)**
You can use the `Pseudoclass` to select the 2 and 4 div.

```
.row div:nth-child(2n) {
/* Your CSS Style */
}
```

If the content  inside  the 2 and 4 div are `inline/inline-block`, just use `text-align: center;`.

**Demo**

Here is the simple demo for the `pseudoclass`.

```css
.row > div {
padding: 10px;
}

.row > div:nth-child(2n) {
color: #fff;
background: red;
text-align: center;
height: 50px;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<div>One</div>
<div>Two</div>
<div>Three</div>
<div>Four</div>
</div>
```

Hope this is helpful for you.
Thanks.

Comment: That just centers it horizontally. I want to center it vertical too.

Comment: I have given only the demo, for your concern you can add "display: flex" and "align-item: center;" and  "justify-content: center;" property to align vertically and horizontally center.

Comment: "align-items: center;"

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex properties to make your content to center.

for more details, you can check

> [Flexbox: center horizontally and vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026884/flexbox-center-horizontally-and-vertically)

Comment: I have tried implementing this, but it didn't change a thing.

Comment: How did you implement this. Can you share your code.?

Answer (score 0):

Try a different approach. Bootstrap's floating grid system will not get you where you want.

First, remove `row` and `col-` classes so you have something like this:

```
<div class="my-row">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Then use CSS to achieve the same result as before, but with the content aligned center:

```
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .my-row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
  }

  .my-row > div {
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

If you are using SASS, then replace hardcoded 992px with the `@screen-md-min` variable.

---

Here's a JsFiddle of your simplified example:
https://jsfiddle.net/mpnz9b30/1/

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="col-md-6 nopadding cinfo">
    <div class="clientinfo">
        <h3>IVEY</h3>
        <p>Clarksville, TN</p>
        <div class="social-icons-clients">
            <a href="#"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-ig">&nbsp;</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-fb">&nbsp;</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-gp">&nbsp;</span></a>
            <a href="#"><span class="icon-sprite sprite-sc">&nbsp;</span></a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/contracoda" target="_blank">
                <span class="icon-sprite sprite-tw">&nbsp;</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```